# Can I pass the a reference of an NSWindow to a custom object and use that object to add an NSButton and Action?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton

I was wondering if it's possible to pass the reference of an NSWindow to a custom object and then use that object to to add an NSButton and associated action/selector for that button.

I seem to be running into issues when I attempt this.  When I run the sample program and click on the button, the following runtime error occurs:
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)

Here is my code:

```
//  AppDelegate.h

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

//  AppDelegate.m

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "CustomObject.h"
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    CustomObject *test = [[CustomObject alloc]init];
    [test createButton:_window];
}
@end


//  CustomObject.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CustomObject : NSObject
{
    int test;
    NSButton *testButton;
}
- (IBAction)pressCustomButton:(id)sender;

-(void)createButton:(NSWindow*)win;
@end

//  CustomObject.m

#import "CustomObject.h"

@implementation CustomObject

-(IBAction)pressCustomButton:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"pressCustomButton");
}

-(void)createButton:(NSWindow*)win
{
    testButton = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 200, 50)];

    [[win contentView] addSubview: testButton];
    [testButton setTitle: @"Button title!"];
    [testButton setButtonType:NSMomentaryLightButton]; //Set what type button You want
    [testButton setBezelStyle:NSRoundedBezelStyle]; //Set what style You want

    [testButton setTarget:self];
    [testButton setAction:@selector(pressCustomButton:)];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I assume you're using Automatic Reference Counting.

When you click the button, the app attempts to call the `pressCustomButton:` method of the target of the button, which the instance of `CustomObject` set to be itself. However, that instance of `CustomObject` has already been deallocated.

Take the following code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    CustomObject *test = [[CustomObject alloc]init];
    [test createButton:_window];
}
```

Once that method is finished being called, if you are using ARC, the `CustomObject` instance you created will be released. Since `NSControl` subclasses like `NSButton` don't retain their targets (to avoid retain cycles/strong reference cycles), this will also cause the `CustomObject` instance to be deallocated. This will cause any subsequent messages to that instance to produce unexpected results such as a crash.

To prevent this, you'll need to keep the `CustomObject` instance around beyond the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method. There are a couple of ways of doing that, such as making it a property of the `AppDelegate`, or if you plan on having multiple objects, use an `NSMutableArray` to store them in.

Something like the following:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
....
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *customObjects;
@end

//  AppDelegate.m

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "CustomObject.h"
@implementation AppDelegate

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
         customObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    CustomObject *test = [[CustomObject alloc]init];
    [customObjects addObject:test];
    [test createButton:_window];
}
@end
```